# Angular text disappears when reopened

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my code, I am displaying a paragraph and I want the user to change that paragraph and save it. So that the paragraph is updated and new. The component on which the text is displayed is a side panel of the main page. The code works, the user can edit the data and when saved, you can see it's updated in the network. But when I reopen the page, the old text is back as if I haven't done anything to it even though it has changed. My code is below, I searched, but I can't figure out the problem and what should I do to fix it.

HTML:

```
<div class="h-100-p" fxLayout="column" fusePerfectScrollbar>
        <div class="group mt-32">
            <div fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                <header class="purple-fg" style="font-size:18.72px"><strong>Sticker Info:</strong></header>
            </div>
            <p>
                <span contenteditable [textContent]="_stickerData?.StickerData" (input)="onStickerDataChange($event.target.innerHTML)">
                    {{_stickerData?.StickerData}}
                </span>
            </p>          
        </div>
    </div>
                <button mat-button matRipple class="purple-500 fuse-white-fg mr-12" (click)="save()"> Update Sticker </button>
```

TS:

```
 private _stickerData: IStickerData;

@Input()
  set StickerData(prm: IStickerData) {
      if (this._stickerData != prm) {
          this._stickerData = prm;
      }
  }
  get StickerData(): IStickerData {
      return this._stickerData;
  }

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IStickerData>;


    constructor(
    private _productionService: ProductionService,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
        ) {}
    
      ngOnInit() {
      }
    
      onStickerDataChange(data) {
        this._stickerData.StickerData = data;
    }
    save(){
        this.confirmDialogRef = this._dialog.open(FuseConfirmDialogComponent, {
            disableClose: false,
        });
        
        this.confirmDialogRef.componentInstance.confirmMessage =
        "Sticker will be changed.";
    
    this.confirmDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
        if (result) {
            this._productionService
                .saveStickerData(this._stickerData)
                .subscribe((response: IStickerData) => {
                    this._stickerData = response;
                    this._messages.Show(
                        "Sticker is updated",
                        3
                    );
                    this.cd.markForCheck();
                });
        }
    });
    
    }
```

TS for service:

```
saveStickerData(data: IStickerData): Observable<IStickerData> {
        return this._http.post("Production/SaveStickerData", data);
    }
```

Comment: you verified from API , you getting updated data from API or old data after refresh ?

Comment: I did, yes I am getting updated data

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the data from where it's being saved.

Update your service file by adding a get function for the data. Something like...

`production.service.ts`

```js
getStickerData(): Observable<IStickerData> {
  return this.httpClient.get("Production/GetStickerData")
}
```

Then invoke the function in your app component:

`app.component.ts`

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.productionService.getStickerData()
    .subscribe(data => this._stickerData.StickerData = data)
}
```

That should populate the paragraph with saved and updated data from production...

Comment: I have a GetStickerDataList in my service so I called it in ngOnInit like this;
`this._productionService.getStickerDataList(this.Filter).subscribe((response: any) => this._stickerData.StickerData = response)`
But it gave a `TypeError: Cannot set property 'StickerData' of undefined` error when I opened the page

Comment: `_stickerData` seems to have a private access modifier to it. I'm assuming this is preventing it from being read in the DOM when the page loads... So, try removing any access modifier to the property (i.e. make it public)

Comment: I made it public. Yet, I still get the same error. Don't know what the problem is.

Comment: This is a part of the error I get;
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'StickerData' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (sticker-preview.component.ts:54)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122) `